# rails 3: how can my app send from multiple email accounts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

In my environment.rb file I have:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.example_host.com",
  :port => '25',
  :domain => "example_send_from.com",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => "send_account_name",
  :password => ENV['MY_EMAIL_SEND_PWD']
}
```

It works fine.

However, now my app has a new class of emails that need to be sent via a different email account... perhaps gmail in some low-volume cases, sendgrid in other high volume cases.

I'm sure it's pretty simple -- but how do I override the default `Base.smtp_settings` setting on an email-by-email basis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do you have separate actionmailers for each email account? then you could set the smtp settings per action mailer-class:

```
class Mailer1 < ....
  self.smtp_settings = { .... }
end
```

etc.

Comment: no, we just have the one entry in the environment file... not sure what to do to allow creating more than one actionmailer, or how to specify which one is used for a particular type of email that's going out.

Comment: right - removed the 'normal' config from environment.rb, then did it at the top of each MyMailClass file using self.smtp_settings = { custom config hash for each account }